# Mapstruct mapper in src/test/java not generated by maven build

Tags: mapstruct

Just as the title says, I have a mapper interface in `src/test/java`, which is not generated by the mapstruct processor.

In the same project, all mappers in `src/main/java` are generated. Is this expected behaviour?

How do I generate the mappers inside the test sources?

Edit (more info):

Simplified Maven module structure:

```
root_project
-> module_1
```

pom.xml of `root_project`

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
```

The pom.xml of `module_1` is basically empty:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How did you set up the annotation processor? Can you share your POM or similar?

Comment: How does the plugin look like in the build part of the POM? The configuration in the pluginManagement looks OK.

Comment: How is the compilation invoked? The maven compiler plugin has `compile` and `testCompile` phases. If you only run `mvn compile` then only the application sources are compiled.

Comment: @Filip there is no `build` tag, it's all implicit. I build with `clean install`. I recreated a new project setup just and it works as expected, so the mistake must be in the configuration of the old project . I'll update this question if I find anything.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and fixed it changing the maven compiler plugin version.
Please notice the versions: **Compiler 3.5.1** and **Mapstruct 1.1.0.Final**

```
            <!-- compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```